# Is it possible for an inner classes to inherit extensions from outer classes in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes

If for example, classes C and D each stood to benefit from being a subclass of B; Is it possible for these inner classes to inherit the extension from the outer class as opposed to extending each one individually?

```
public class A extends B {
    public class C {          

    }

    public class D {    

    }
}
```

Comment: can you point an example where this would be meaningful/useful?

Comment: Using the TestNG framework, I have `@BeforeSuite`, `@AfterSuite`, `@BeforeClass`..etc in class "B" which is inherited by the `@Test` classes("A" in this example) and are executed for each test suite/class/method accordingly. However, if I run an `@Test` method from an inner class of "A", none of the setup/teardown methods in class "B" are executed.

Answer (score 0):

It will be terribly confusing to make C and D extend B.

Instances of C and D already have access to an enclosing instance of a B object, so can access B's fields and methods.

Comment: Agreed. I think it makes sense to do it in my situation(described in response to the comment above), but not much else. I can see why this sort of thing wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Class C and Class D will have access to all members of Class A.

Class C and Class D will have access to protected and public members of Class B if class B is in another package.

Class C and Class D will have access to default, protected and public members of Class B if class B is in same package.

How ever we need to note that both class C and class D doesn't extent Class A. They both extent Object